# Making table in Email while making backup in email

Tags: android

I have made an app that needs to make a backup of data in an email. I was searching whether i could make a table in email and than fit data onto it dynamically.is it possible?

```
 public void sendEmail(){
    Intent emailIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,email_global);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Backup of date:"+date_global+"  Session:"+session_global);
    Toast.makeText(this,getResult(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(getResult()));


    try{
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send Mail..."));
        finish();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

and

```
   public String getResult(){
    String result="<html><body><table border=\"1\"><tr><th>vendor_id</th><th>type</th><th>amount</th><th>remarks</th>"+"</tr>";
    db=dbhandler.getDb();

    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM vendor_transaction where session='"+session_global+"'";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            int vendor_id=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("vendor_id"));
            int type=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("type"));
            String amount=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("amount"));
            String remarks=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("remarks"));
            result+="<tr><td>"+vendor_id+"</td><td>"+type+"</td><td>"+amount+"</td><td>"+remarks+"</td></tr>";
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        result+="</table></body></html>";
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return result;

}
```

[image]

Comment: You must use HTML for creating tables. Hope you know what are HTML formatted Emails

Comment: @DakshAgrawal thanks for your reply...Can you please provide me a relevant source for it?

Comment: How are you sending Emails? Through Intent or through some web service or PHP? Please tell so that I can get you specific code.

Comment: @DakshAgrawal I am sending through intent..

Comment: @DakshAgrawal please read my edited question and point me where did i missed...

Comment: What problems are you facing??

Comment: @DakshAgrawal i did not got a data in a table . In fact all the data are in a single row in email..

Comment: Can you send screenshots?

Comment: Open it in gmail

Comment: @DakshAgrawal please see the updated question

Comment: its the same problem..

Comment: Long way but will result in good testing-   Log the HTML & create a file and check if the HTML is well formed

Comment: yes it is well formed..

Comment: It looks well in Browser??

Comment: @DakshAgrawal yes it does...table will appear if i save the text in html but table is not formed inside email...

Comment: Seems quite tricky...will test and tell you tomorrow. OK??

Comment: Ok thankyou very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this code for sending

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, the_body);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

You can create a default mail layout through a nice template and create a table layout with some text fields like `{{enter_data_here}}` and put them in string variables. Make a loop and fill data through `String.replace("{{enter_data_here}}",data);` . I am not so good at HTML so can't guide you more with that. You can find more code on the net.